# Sort dates and show the non-duplicates

Tags: jquery, parsing, object

I have this in my javascript code:

```
function parsePerObject(data){
    // LOOP OBJECTS
    var content = "";
    $.each(data, function(key, value){ 
        content += "<li class='contentblock has-thumb'>";
        content += "<p><a href='/sessions/view/" + value.id + "'>" + value.name + "</p>";      
        content += "<p>" + value.starttime + " - " + value.endtime + "</p>";
        content += "<p>" + value.speaker + "</p>";             
    });

    $("#here").append(content);
}
```

I want to loop through the data. The data are a series of objects like this:

```
{
    "21114"
    {
        "id":"21114",
        "external_id":"",
        "sessiongroupid":"1844",
        "eventid":"5588",
        "order":"0",
        "name":"localStorage HTML5 Session",
        "description":"localstorage",
        "starttime":"2013-04-23 12:00:00",
        "endtime":"2013-04-23 13:30:00",
        "speaker":"",
        "location":"",
        "mapid":"0",
        "xpos":"0.000000",
        "ypos":"0.000000",
        "maptype":"plan",
        "imageurl":"",
        "presentation":"",
        "organizer":"0",
        "twitter":"",
        "allowAddToFavorites":"0",
        "allowAddToAgenda":"0",
        "votes":"0",
        "url":"",
        "venueid":"0"
    },
    "21116"
    {
        //etc
    },
    //etc
}
```

But now I want to sort the data according to the date.
Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to transform your object into an array, then use [JavaScript's excellent Array.sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparison function.

http://jsfiddle.net/2BY5x/1/

```
function parsePerObject(data){
    // Turn the data object into an array
    var dataArray = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        dataArray.push(value);
    });

    // Sort data by starttime
    dataArray.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.starttime > b.starttime) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.starttime < b.starttime) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    // LOOP OBJECTS
    var content = "";
    $.each(dataArray, function(i, item){
        content += "<li class='contentblock has-thumb'>";
        content += "<p><a href='/sessions/view/" + item.id + "'>" + item.name + "</p>";      
        content += "<p>" + item.starttime + " - " + item.endtime + "</p>";
        content += "<p>" + item.speaker + "</p>";             
    });

    $("#here").append(content);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! And how can I make headers for example for each day? (ex. 2013-03-10) And then a list from the sessions that day?

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could do it. The first one that occurs to me is to create a dates array. If the starttime isn't already there, add it to the array AND place a header. If it is already there, do nothing. http://jsfiddle.net/2BY5x/2/